# Virtual pupilary distance plug-in

Tags: wordpress, mobile, plugins, desktop-application, jobs

Looking for a plug-in that is similar to a demo on trylive.com; it's a virtual PD app for my company. The company no longer exists so there's no contact number. Looking for someone to emulate the app for Windows and Apple based devices.

Comment: This question is broad and doesn't relate to what stackoverflow is about. Also, If you're seeking someone to do a job, then I recommend adding a job to the side section.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.